# Are there direct flights between Hong Kong and Honolulu?

Tags: air-travel

This [FlyerTalk](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/hawaii/1742040-hong-kong-hawaii-shortest-flight-suggestions-pls.html) forum posts didn't mention any, just flights with at least 1 connection.

Are there truly not even seasonal flights, like in winter in HK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page for HNL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_K._Inouye_International_Airport#Passenger) does not list any passenger flights to/from Hong Kong (there are cargo flights).

Searches on Google Flights on a variety of dates do not yield any results either.

Not a definitive answer (difficult to prove a negative without doing an exhaustive search), but it seems that it's indeed the current situation.